# Google EndPoint not getting called when request has google plus profile url as parameter

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-plus, google-cloud-endpoints

My app uses Google App Engine as backend and it provides google plus & facebook login option to user.

One of the endpoint Api takes user profile picture url as input parameter and tries to store it in the user profile table. My endpoint Api was not getting called successfully when user choose the option of google plus as login,

I have narrowed down the issue to find out that it only happens during google plus login scenario and from the backend logs I see the issue is only because of below parameter which is profile photo url.

```
https:%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2F-xPc6TIzQiFA%2FAAAAAAAAAAI%2FAAAAAAAAAeU%2FUIIpz-4G1dQ%2Fphoto.jpg%3Fsz=400
```

Backend Request from logs(Data changed for privacy reasons).

```
/_ah/api/registrationAPI/v2/XXXXXX/Rahul%20Purswani/rahulfhp@gmail.com/https:%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2F-xPc6TIzQiFA%2FAAAAAAAAAAI%2FAAAAAAAAAeU%2FUIIpz-4G1dQ%2Fphoto.jpg%3Fsz=400/XXX/YYY/VVV, returning NOBODY to imply authentication is in progress.
```

**My Api Class Declaration :**

```
@Api(name="registrationAPI",
        version="v2",
     namespace=@ApiNamespace(ownerDomain="backend.XXX.XXX.YY",ownerName="backend.XXX.XXX.YY",packagePath=""))
public class PlayerRegistrationEndPoint {

}
```

And to my surprise this only happens when I test the Api on local development server through real device. If I deploy my api all works fine, I have spent almost the day to narrow it down, If you have any clue about it that will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you accidentally logging the bytes of your pictures using logging.info(), logging.error(), print, etc?  Logging bytes to either the logger or standard out can make the dev instances (or even production instance) go into zombie mode.

This has happened to me many times.  Check all logs to make sure you aren't trying to log something that isn't a basic variable type.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue since we migrated our code base from Eclipse to Android Studio, during this migration our app-engine sdk version got changed from 1.9.22 to 1.9.18.

Looking back and doing comparative analysis with why it used to work with eclipse, I tried using 1.9.22 app-engine sdk here and issue got resolved, the zombie behavior is no more and even in development environment everything is stable now.

I also checked & removed all the loggers and out statements, though the issue was not fixed with trying that alone.

Thanks for even letting me know that it can also go wrong in future during development environment testing.